# Problem with top 10 rows in a sql query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

As a beginner in Sql Server 2005, i should get some help in getting top 10 from a table.

The scenario is like, a table Invitecount has multiple records for each userid. i have distinct userid's with the following sql query

```
Select distinct(userid) from inviteCount
```

For each userid, i get the number of points using the following query

```
Select sum(points) from invitecount 
where UserID = 126429
```

And after i get the sum, i should have top 10 users with max points. My problem here is with writing all these statements together using arrays, etc.

IF someone could help me, i really appreciate it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: As the answers tell you you can do this without arrays, or anything else. You can specify this all in one query.

Comment: Try going for an SQL tutorial; that will teach you those things. I just googled, and the first hit was: http://www.tizag.com/sqlTutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like:

```
select top 10
    userid,
    pointstotal = sum(points)
from
    invitecount
group by userid
order by sum(points) desc
```

Note the order by.

A fancier version would be

```
select 
    userid
    pointstotal = sum(points) over (partition by userid),
    row_number = row_number() over (partition by userid order by sum(points) desc)
from 
    invitecount i
where 
    row_number <= 10
```

(untested - so probably needs a tweak)

Comment: More interesting version of the second query would be to use `RANK` or `DENSE_RANK` to deal with ties, etc. `ROW_NUMBER` will arbitrarily discard tied results.

Comment: What would be the benefit of the fancier version?

Comment: @abe: i just included it for fun, and for learning! The techniques are overkill for this situation, but worth reading up on. One thing though is the avoidance of a groupby which might be awkward for some queries.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
SELECT TOP 10 userID, SUM(Points)
FROM inviteCount
GROUP BY UserId
ORDER BY SUM(Points) desc
```

I'm not sure what you mean by using arrays, but this would get you the top ten userIds ordered by the sum of points.

Comment: Thank youuuu.. I was unaware of group by :)Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Select TOP 10 userid, sum(points) from inviteCount group by userid order by sum(points) desc
```